# angularjs select box set object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my angular

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.projectObj = {"proId":"33","proName":"samal"}
  $scope.projectArr = [{"proName":"samal","proId":"33"},{"proName":"aaa","proId":"47"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"48"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"49"},{"proName":"sddd","proId":"50"},{"proName":"dddd","proId":"51"},{"proName":"ttt","proId":"52"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"53"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"54"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"55"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"56"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"57"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"58"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"59"},{"proName":"sdf","proId":"60"}]
})
```

this is my select box

```
<select ng-model="projectObj">
   <option value="{{item}}" ng-repeat="item in projectArr">{{item.proName}}</option>
</select>
```

**$scope.projectObj** is already assign with an object and it is already inside  **$scope.projectArr**. what is want is when i load the html file $scope.projectObj `proName` should be pre-selected.how can i do this. this is my [pluker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fk2JLEoGtRJhegplYC6L?p=preview)

Comment: Check my answer it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating `options` isn't preferred way to show select dropdown. I'd suggest you to to use `ng-options` directive to get object binding on `ng-model`

```
<select  flex ng-model="projectObj" 
  ng-options="item as item.proName for item in projectArr">
</select>
```

And then assign `projectObj` from `projectArr`.

```
$scope.projectObj  = $scope.projectArr[0];
```

[**Demo here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/f9G8AKw5SzLAFA215Dct?p=preview)

---

Use `md-select` for Angular material like below and use `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.proId'` for directly pre select object. Additionally you have to follow `Dot Rule` while defining `ng-model`

**Markup**

```
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="projectObj" placeholder="Select a state"
    ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.proId'}">
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in projectArr">
      {{ item.proName }}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrBzqz)

Comment: thing is i'm using angular material design for my app. when i'm using ng option its not supported in material

Comment: @IT13122256RanawakaR.A.S.M look at the updated answer please

Comment: i want to remove this `$scope.projectObj  = $scope.projectArr[0];` and only use like this       `$scope.projectObj = {"proId":"33","proName":"samal"}`. then its not working y is that. both are same to in my knowledge

Comment: @IT13122256RanawakaR.A.S.M no, `$scope.projectObj  = $scope.projectArr[0];` is taking object from same array reference, where as the `$scope.projectObj = {"proId":"33","proName":"samal"}` creates a new reference

Comment: thing is i'm getting the array and object from separate request and if i use `$scope.projectObj = $scope.projectArr[0]` then i need to loop through `projectArr` array get the object and assign it to `projectObj `

Comment: @IT13122256RanawakaR.A.S.M you could use `track by` for the same, check udpated answer

Comment: thanks bro. now it's work like i want. appreciate all the help

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700616/how-to-make-scrollbar-scroll-horizontally-on-right-and-left-on-click-of-next-and

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-selected. This will work.

```
<option value="{{item}}" ng-selected="item" ng-repeat="item in projectArr">{{item.proName}}</option>
```